# Remove Duplicate values from a list while keeping track of the removed items' indexes

Tags: c#, list, merge

I have two lists. One is a string list of players and the other one is an int list that represents the number of mentions for each player. (for each element in the players list, there is one in the number of mentions list). There are duplicate players in the list of players, for example there are 3 players "player 1"s with 5,10,13 number of mentions in the NumofMentions list. I want to eliminate duplicate values but keep the sum of the number of mentions. For the aforementioned example, I want to have one "player1" with the number of mentions 28.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you show us a the code instead of describing what you want to achieve

Comment: Because my code is awful :) It connects to Google Big Query, makes tons of queries and gets JSON responses. Then tries to interpret those responses and comes down to those two arrays that I mentioned. Imagine a beginner code that does something like this. Looks like a mess and I can hardly understand what I did myself. I was afraid if I shared the code, my reputation would go below 7 :D

Comment: Can you prepare [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: I have a couple of suggestions in the answers below, I will try them and if no luck, I will prepare the example. Thank you very much for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your player name and values go hand in hand, perhaps they shouldn't belong in 2 separate lists but a list of class player. You haven't shown us any code so we have to work with our own interpretations of your problem, but here's how I would approach it...

```
public class Player
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public void MyTest()
{
    var myList = new List<Player>
    {
        new Player { name = "Player 1", value = 5 },
        new Player { name = "Player 1", value = 10 },
        new Player { name = "Player 1", value = 13 },
        new Player { name = "Player 2", value = 3 },
        new Player { name = "Player 2", value = 4 },
        new Player { name = "Player 2", value = 6 }
    };

    var mySummedList = myList.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(x => new Player { name = x.Key, value = x.Sum(y => y.value)});

    foreach(var val in mySummedList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", val.name, val.value));
    }
}

//Output:
//Player 1: 28
//Player 2: 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a List; use a Dictionary

```
var mentions = new Dictionary<string, int>();
mentions["PlayerName"] = 5;

var currentCount = mentions["PlayerName"];
mentions["PlayerName"] = currentCount + amountToAdd;
```

You can still get all the players from the Dictionary's Keys property

```
foreach(var player in mentions.Keys)
{
    //do some work
}
```

Given you have four lists coming in, do the following for each list:

```
foreach(var playerCounter in googleQueryList)
{
   if(mentions.ContainsKey(playerCounter.Name))
   {
        //Update the player here
        var currentCount = mentions[player.Name];
        mentions[player.Name] = currentCount + playerCounter.NumOfMentions;
   }
   else
   {
        //Add the player here
        mentions[player.Name] = playerCounter.NumOfMentions;
   }
}
```

Comment: The two lists come from sql queries from Google Big Query. There are 4, two lists of players and two lists of number of mentions. I concat the players to one list and the number of mentions to another. That's why players list has duplicate values. I don't know how to do it with dictionary. Can you please give me a more detaiked example?

Comment: Updated it based on that; do that for each list of the number of mentions, and you'll have a complete dictionary of the players with the counts. You don't have to iterate over the whole list to find a player then, you can look it up directly via the indexer.